# I no longer have iLife.app in my Applications folder

Tags: macos, ilife

I no longer have iLife.app in my application's folder. The latest version of iLife I have is iLife 11 from Snow Leopard: OS X 10.8.6, which resides on my MacPro 1,1.

I purchased my new iMac (2013 27″) new from B&H, in SEPT 2014, Serial Number: D25N116JF8JC; it came with the Mavericks operating system. However, in late 2014 I upgraded it to Yosemite online. I didn't like it because Yosemite no longer had colored folders and text instead it only had colored dots, so I took my iMac to an Apple Store in King-of-Prussia, Pennsylvania had them return my operating system back to Mavericks.

I must have lost iLife at this time.

I have now upgraded my operating system back to Yosemite. But, I have lost my iLife app altogether. So I cannot upgrade iDVD which is now 7.0.3, and now I get an error message saying I cannot upgrade iDVD to the next level. Also my iMovie HD.app is 6.0.3. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. iLife is a folder of apps but I think you know that. I'll try to answer a general procedure on how to restore those apps...  If you have a follow on question try to ask that as a narrower query.

Answer (score 1):

iLife 11 was sold on physical media, find the iLife box or the restore media that contained it, and you should be able to reinstall from that.

Or a trip to the Genius Bar should get that resolved too.

Comment: Are you thinking that the user had both the iLife apps that came from the app store and the older ones from a migrated HD? If so this is technically correct, but wouldn't it be better to restore the correct / new versions of the app instead? Also, I was tempted to vote -1 since the genius bar really doesn't do software support anymore - see my answer for details.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware and it's sad that they no longer do software support; I think it accounted for at least 50% of Mac reservations when I used to work as a Genius and I think it's invaluable to a lot of customers. Albert seems to have a mixed up version of iLife installed and he seems to concern about iDVD, which is only available fresh from the iLife DVD (updates are installed using Mac App Store since 10.8). For iMovie and GarageBand, Albert should be able to download a fresh copy again from Mac App Store if he had previously accepted the copy offered by App Store when he upgraded…

Comment: Yes - the timing of the hardware appointments and the iPhone / iOS revenue means that the genius queue is dwarfed by repairing / troubleshooting those devices in 10 minute slots. You can still connect with someone to troubleshoot software, but it's far more rare in 2015 to get that availability or assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your Mac is with most new apps where you get a digital download (one time) of the various iLife apps:

- Garageband
- Photos or iPhotos
- iMovie

Similarly - iWork (Pages, Numbers, Keynote) are digital downloads that you will have lost as well.

1. These apps would all be on your backup - get them there first if you can.
2. These apps are assigned to your Apple ID - so sign in to the Mac App store with your Apple ID and re-download them.
3. If you have none of the above that work - you could call Apple Support and explain you didn't know to redeem / back them up. They should be able to look at your serial number and grant a re-download code if you meet their requirements for an original Mac purchaser.

As you've found - the genius bar really doesn't do software service anymore. Much better to call or request help online first:

- https://www.apple.com/support/mac-apps/

Choose one app you want to download - then choose contact us link to get in touch with a support person.